# Mini Batching Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, mini-batch

I'm trying to implement mini batching correctly for my own NN.

But I can't wrap my head about what's being summed? Do I sum the Gradient or the delta weights (where the learning rate is already multiplied) for the weight and bias which in my example are:

Delta Weight: `activation'(neurons) ⊗ Error * learningRate x input`

Delta Bias: `activation'(neurons) ⊗ Error * learningRate`

Do I also divide those summed delta weights or gradients throug the batch size?

EDIT:

So all **questions summed:**

- Is the delta weight without the learning rate called the gradient?
- Do I need to add up those delta weights with or without the learning rate multiplied
- So I must save two seperate Gradients? (Bias + Weight)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching for a whole night and looking at lots of blogs / articles I came to these answers (which work for me!)

1) Nevermind, people call both the "gradient"

2) without the
    learning rate

3) Yes, when finishing the batch you multiply the
    learning rate (... and do momentum optimization if implemented)